# Как получить return от ajax?

Tags: ajax, javascript

Используется стандартный ajax запрос(самописный(!) не jquery), каких в интернете много. Всё прекрасно работает, но результат нельзя отретёрнить(return). Его можно вывести алертом(alert), его можно записать в див(`$('content').innerHTML = result;`), но его не получается вернуть из функции. Почему?

Код:

```
ajax.get = function (url) {
    var XMLHttp = createXmlHttp();
    XMLHttp.open("get", url, true);
    XMLHttp.send(null);
    XMLHttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (XMLHttp.readyState == 4) {
            if (XMLHttp.status == 200) {
                var qR = XMLHttp.responseText; * *
                return qR; * * << < ------возвращаетundefined
            } else {
                alert("error!_!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

всё предельно просто, почитайте про асинхронное выполнение кода:

```
var qR;
XMLHttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (XMLHttp.readyState == 4) {
        if (XMLHttp.status == 200) {
            qR = XMLHttp.responseText; 
        } else {
            alert("error!_!");
        }
    }
}
$('content').innerHTML = qR; // примерно так
```

---

##### UPD1:

говорю же, почитайте про асинхронное выполнение кода, в вашем случае необходимо передавать вторым параметром в ajax.get callback, который в нём выполнять, обновил ответ

```
ajax.get = function (url, callback) {
    var XMLHttp = createXmlHttp();
    XMLHttp.open("get", url, true);
    XMLHttp.send(null);
    XMLHttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (XMLHttp.readyState == 4) {
            if (XMLHttp.status == 200) {
                callback(XMLHttp.responseText); 
            } else {
                alert("error!_!");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

а вызывать следующим образом:

```
ajax.get(/*url*/, function(resp){
    $('content').innerHTML = resp;
})
```

Comment: нет. немного неправильно меня поняли. Мне надо чтобы происходило следующее:
$('content').innerHTML = ajax.get('blablabla');
что бы при таком вызове аякс вызывался с параметром и возвращал данные вставляя их там куда присвою. так он возвращает undefined

Comment: говорю же, почитайте про асинхронное выполнение кода, в вашем случае необходимо передавать вторым параметром в ajax.get callback, который в нём выполнять, обновил ответ

Comment: я так понял что никаким мега хитрым способом не получится именно возвращать значение? Просто позарез нужна именно конструкция с возвращением.

Comment: Спросил гугла (от своего имени, не от Вашего). Он дал кучу ссылок. Вот две:

    http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Snippets:_Synchronous_AJAX

    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133310/how-can-i-get-jquery-to-perform-a-synchronous-rather-than-asynchronous-ajax-re

Answer (score 0):

ajax-запрос может быть и синхронным, но тогда браузер "подвиснет" на время запроса данных, что нехорошо

Comment: "Когда нельзя, но очень хочется -- то можно". Тут или висеть, или не возвращать результат, которого ещё нет

Comment: да это то я знал. думал может человеческая хитрость заставит асинхронный ретёрнить всетаки.. всем СПАСИБО. тема закрыта