# return в ajax запросе

Tags: ajax

Есть функция, которая возвращает `id` пользователя, если он авторизирован.
Но вот проблема такая, не пойму как сделать что бы `ajax` запрос возвращал данные

```
function getUserId(){
  var id;

  $.ajax({
    url: api,
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
      action: 'getUserId'
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
        if(data.status == 'success'){
            id = data.u_id
        }
      }
  })
  return id;
}
```

Вызываю функцию, возвращает `undefined`

Объявлял переменую `id` вне функции - аналогично все.

Как быть?

Нужно что бы функция `getUserId()` возвращала `id` пользователя

Если на прямую в запросе алертом вывести `data.u_id` - выводит...

Comment: есть полно аналогичных вопросов: 

http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/226606/%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-ajax-data-%D0%B2-return-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8

http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/167243/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-return-%D0%BE%D1%82-ajax?rq=1

Comment: На самом деле, этот вопрос в интернете задавался тысячи раз. Если нет проблем с английским языком, то можно прочитать [этот развёрнутый ответ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call#answer-14220323).

Answer (score 2):

Так сделать нельзя, так как функция асинхронная.

Всё что вы можете, это присвоить значение id некой переменной и/или продолжить выполнение вручную, вызвав некую функцию-продолжение внутри коллбэка `success`.

Например:

```
$.ajax({
    success: function (data) {
        nextStep(data.id);
    }
});

function nextStep (id) {
    // продолжаем работу
}
```

Answer (score 0):

А почему не файрнуть ивент, когда запрос выполнится?

```
var obj = $.('.el'); //Или что угодно
$.ajax({
success: function (data) {
    id = data;
    el.trigger('dataInside');
}
});
```

Ну и где-нибудь держать `.on` на этот `obj`, который будет хватать `id`.